# Vala Panel AppMenu menus are too close together

Tags: xfce, panel, appmenu, vala

I installed Vala Panel AppMenu in Xfce, but in the global menubar, menus are too close together. How can I fix this?

I use the vertex-maia-light theme.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I tried to install `xfce4-appmenu-plugin` through my terminal emulator and got this:

[image: appmenu in xfce-panel]

You no need to add any repository because it is in native ubuntu repository. Before doing the installation, I have tried to compile the [source of vala-panel-appmenu here](https://gitlab.com/vala-panel-project/vala-panel-appmenu), but it was not working for me. So, I remove all of this: `unity-gtk-module-common`, `unity-gtk2-module`, `unity-gtk3-module`, `appmenu-qt`. But, when you install `xfce4-appmenu-plugin`, they would be installed as its dependencies.